# How exactly LAST_VALUE() works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

According to definition: 
**The LAST_VALUE() function is a window function that returns the last value in an ordered partition of a result set.**

So in my example I need to grab the last ExpirationDate date based on QuoteID.

Using `FIRST_VALUE()`  ordered by `QuoteID DESC` produces correct result.

So I am expecting using `LAST_VALUE()` ordered by `QuoteID ASC` should producer the same result.

However it gives me incorrect result.

Am I missing something?

```
  DECLARE @Table TABLE ( QuoteID int, PolicyNumber varchar(100), ExpirationDate date)
 INSERT INTO @Table
 (
     QuoteID,
     PolicyNumber,
     ExpirationDate
 )
 VALUES
 (
     1, -- QuoteID - int
     'Pol1', -- PolicyNumber - varchar
     '2019-05-01' -- ExpirationDate - date
 ),
  (
     2, -- QuoteID - int
     'Pol1', -- PolicyNumber - varchar
     '2018-05-01' -- ExpirationDate - date
 )


 SELECT QuoteID, [@Table].ExpirationDate    ,[@Table].PolicyNumber
    ,CAST(FIRST_VALUE(ExpirationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY QuoteID DESC) AS DATE) as FIRST_VALUE_ExpirationDate --Correct
    ,CAST(LAST_VALUE(ExpirationDate) OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber ORDER BY QuoteID ) AS DATE) as LAST_VALUE_ExpirationDate --Gives Incorrect 
 FROM @Table 
 ORDER BY QuoteID
```

[image]

Comment: Post sample data that corresponds to your result and explain what is wrong with it.

Comment: @Serdia . . . I generally use `first_value()` because `last_value()` has some quirks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per docs on [LAST_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/last-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> The default range is "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT
>   ROW".

And the LAST_VALUE in that range is always the CURRENT ROW

So change to:

```
  DECLARE @Table TABLE ( QuoteID int, PolicyNumber varchar(5), ExpirationDate date)
 INSERT INTO @Table
 (
     QuoteID,
     PolicyNumber,
     ExpirationDate
 )
 VALUES
 (
     1, -- QuoteID - int
     'Pol1', -- PolicyNumber - varchar
     '2019-05-01' -- ExpirationDate - date
 ),
  (
     2, -- QuoteID - int
     'Pol1', -- PolicyNumber - varchar
     '2018-05-01' -- ExpirationDate - date
 )


 SELECT QuoteID, t.ExpirationDate    ,t.PolicyNumber
    ,FIRST_VALUE(ExpirationDate) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber 
             ORDER BY QuoteID DESC)  as FIRST_VALUE_ExpirationDate 
    ,LAST_VALUE(ExpirationDate) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY PolicyNumber 
             ORDER BY QuoteID ASC
             RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
     )  as LAST_VALUE_ExpirationDate
 FROM @Table  t
 ORDER BY QuoteID
```

Which outputs:

```
QuoteID     ExpirationDate PolicyNumber FIRST_VALUE_ExpirationDate LAST_VALUE_ExpirationDate
----------- -------------- ------------ -------------------------- -------------------------
1           2019-05-01     Pol1         2018-05-01                 2018-05-01
2           2018-05-01     Pol1         2018-05-01                 2018-05-01
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the right result for your code.

The descending `order by` in your `first_value` keeps 2018-05-01 at the top before it picks it as the first value. With the `last_value`, the ascending `order by` keeps 2019-05-01 at the bottom and so your `last_value` picks it as the last value.